# Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities dll: Missing Assembly, Where to Download?

Tags: ajax, dll, reference, .net-assembly, libraries

This is probably really obvious, but I've been trying to locate this dll for a solid two hours now. Where would I find the library that contains all content relevant to Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities? I have inherited someone's code and it has been a saga. Any help deeply appreciated!!

-F

Comment: This question is off topic for this site because you are asking us to recommend an external resource.

Answer (score 5):

You can install AjaxMin from here: http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/

Comment: The archived link is [http://web.archive.org/web/20210630220827/https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=ajaxmin](http://web.archive.org/web/20210630220827/https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=ajaxmin)